# Compare validator is always firing off even when the passwords are the same

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript

Here's the reason why. This is the generated HTML:

```
    <div>
        <label for="RegisterModel_Password">Contrase&#241;a</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-length="Su Contrase&amp;#241;a debe tener al menos 6 caracteres." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="Debe escribir su contrase&amp;#241;a" id="RegisterModel_Password" name="RegisterModel.Password" type="password" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="RegisterModel.Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="RegisterModel_ConfirmPassword">Confirme Su Contrase&#241;a</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="Sus contrase&amp;#241;as no son las mismas." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="RegisterModel_ConfirmPassword" name="RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword" type="password" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

Notice this, in the confirm password box:

```
data-val-equalto-other="*.Password"
```

This should be `RegisterModel.Password`, as I'm guessing the javascript looks like the input with the name "RegisterModel.Password", no?

Here's my model code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe escribir su contraseña")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Su {0} debe tener al menos {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirme Su Contraseña")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Sus contraseñas no son las mismas.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

---

Just created a brand new MVC3 application and this is the model:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

And the validation works. The only difference here is that they're use the model directly in the view, whereas I'm passing a **View**Model that contains that RegisterModel.

The HTML of this working default is different to mine though:

```
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" type="password" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just confirmed that this caused by what I suspected. I move everything into a single model instead of a ViewModel (as I correctly should), the jQuery validation lib does it's job correctly. I wonder if this is a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I had the same problem than you. This happens because there is a bug on the javascript file that performs the validation. Here is the fix you have to make.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1716181.aspx/1

It is not that hard to find in the minimized version, which is what I had to change.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the above answer didn't fix it for me unfortunately. What did fix it was ensuring that I applied the [Required] and [StringLength(.....] Atrributes identically to both the password and confirm password field. I also had to apply the Compare attribute to the Password field, not the ConfirmPassword field.

So, with the model above,

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe escribir su contraseña")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Su {0} debe tener al menos {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirme Su Contraseña")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Sus contraseñas no son las mismas.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Becomes

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe escribir su contraseña")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Su {0} debe tener al menos {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
[Compare("ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "Sus contraseñas no son las mismas.")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe escribir su contraseña")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Su {0} debe tener al menos {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirme Su Contraseña")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.RegisterConfirmPassword)
```

which outputs

```
   <input data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="RegisterModel.RegisterPassword" id="RegisterModel_RegisterConfirmPassword" name="RegisterModel.RegisterConfirmPassword" type="password">
```

I took the output of the above and added single quotes around **"'RegisterModel.RegisterPassword'"**

```
    <input data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="'RegisterModel.RegisterPassword'" id="RegisterModel_RegisterConfirmPassword" name="RegisterModel.RegisterConfirmPassword" type="password">
```